# Content overlaps my header in Joomla! 3.4.5

Tags: php, css, templates, joomla, header

I am using Joomla! with an Artisteer generated template. I want to put my header in a fixed position so that when I scroll, the header will stay in its position, which I know how to do. However, when I my header is fixed, and I scroll, the content of my site overlaps my header, which does not make any sense to me. Could someone please help me?

```
 .art-header
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url('../images/header.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: just add it in your question, select it and the press the code {} formatting option

Comment: I have now included the code. Could you please help me... Thanks

Comment: I'm not into joomla. But I gave you my vote, maybe someone else with Joomla XP can help you.

Comment: have you seen http://www.artisteer.com/?post_id=203581&p=forum_post&forum_id=13 it could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you must change header z-index to on top canvas with value 9999 and
div/section content z-index to 1.

```css
.art-header
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url('../images/header.jpg');
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asep... Solved my problems!